# WPF ArgumentNullException on ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button in a Window that opens a second Window and it works fine, I tried to add a second button now that also opens a different Window but this one does not seem to work.
I did the exact same code for both Windows except the naming or other smaller things that should not break the code.

When I click the first button the second window shows up perfectly fine and works, but when I click the second button, I get a "System.ArgumentNullException" @ the `.ShowDialog();` function.

Here is the Stacktrace:

```
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindValue(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridItemAttachedStorage.TryGetValue(Object item, DependencyProperty property, Object& value)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.RestoreAttachedItemValue(DependencyObject objectWithProperty, DependencyProperty property)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.SyncProperties(Boolean forcePrepareCells)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow.PrepareRow(Object item, DataGrid owningDataGrid)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, Object item)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.MS.Internal.Controls.IGeneratorHost.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject container, Object item)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator.PrepareItemContainer(DependencyObject container)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.InsertContainer(Int32 childIndex, UIElement container, Boolean isRecycled)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.AddContainerFromGenerator(Int32 childIndex, UIElement child, Boolean newlyRealized, Boolean isBeforeViewport)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild(IItemContainerGenerator& generator, IContainItemStorage& itemStorageProvider, IContainItemStorage& parentItemStorageProvider, Object& parentItem, Boolean& hasUniformOrAverageContainerSizeBeenSet, Double& computedUniformOrAverageContainerSize, Double& computedUniformOrAverageContainerPixelSize, Boolean& computedAreContainersUniformlySized, Boolean& hasAnyContainerSpanChanged, IList& items, Object& item, IList& children, Int32& childIndex, Boolean& visualOrderChanged, Boolean& isHorizontal, Size& childConstraint, Rect& viewport, VirtualizationCacheLength& cacheSize, VirtualizationCacheLengthUnit& cacheUnit, Int64& scrollGeneration, Boolean& foundFirstItemInViewport, Double& firstItemInViewportOffset, Size& stackPixelSize, Size& stackPixelSizeInViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size& stackPixelSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Size& stackLogicalSize, Size& stackLogicalSizeInViewport, Size& stackLogicalSizeInCacheBeforeViewport, Size& stackLogicalSizeInCacheAfterViewport, Boolean& mustDisableVirtualization, Boolean isBeforeFirstItem, Boolean isAfterFirstItem, Boolean isAfterLastItem, Boolean skipActualMeasure, Boolean skipGeneration, Boolean& hasBringIntoViewContainerBeenMeasured, Boolean& hasVirtualizingChildren)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl(Size constraint, Nullable`1& lastPageSafeOffset, List`1& previouslyMeasuredOffsets, Nullable`1& lastPagePixelSize, Boolean remeasure)
   at System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridRowsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.StackMeasureHelper(IStackMeasure measureElement, IStackMeasureScrollData scrollData, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.StackMeasureHelper(IStackMeasure measureElement, IStackMeasureScrollData scrollData, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCell(Int32 cell, Boolean forceInfinityV)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureCellsGroup(Int32 cellsHead, Size referenceSize, Boolean ignoreDesiredSizeU, Boolean forceInfinityV, Boolean& hasDesiredSizeUChanged)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Grid.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Decorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Documents.AdornerDecorator.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Border.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverrideHelper(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Window.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.SetLayoutSize()
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisualInternal(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.set_RootVisual(Visual value)
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisual()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetRootVisualAndUpdateSTC()
   at System.Windows.Window.SetupInitialState(Double requestedTop, Double requestedLeft, Double requestedWidth, Double requestedHeight)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindow(Boolean duringShow)
   at System.Windows.Window.CreateSourceWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.SafeCreateWindowDuringShow()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.Show()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
   at Silverhunter.MainWindow.DisplayCraftScreen_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\leole\source\repos\Silverhunter\Silverhunter\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 83
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()`
```

Also, here is what happens when I click the button:

```
private void DisplayWindow3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window3 window3 = new Window3();
            window3.Owner = this;
            window3.DataContext = _dataContext;
            window3.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Window3:

```
public partial class Window3 : Window
    {
        public GameSession Session => DataContext as GameSession;
        public Window3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Most likely, the instance object in front of your `.ShowDialog()` is the one that is null. Try placing a Breakpoint on the line that contains `.Showdialog()`, and then when it pauses during a debug run on that line, use the "Watch" window to find out the values of your instance.  Also, it would benefit you here if you showed more code, if you still cannot resolve this.

Comment: @TamBui I've set the Breakpoint but do not know what to do next, I never came to this step while debugging. I also do not know what code else you want to see, but I've added the Code that executed when I click on the button.

Comment: Using the debugger is a very common practice (beginners and experts alike), and should not be looked at as a daunting way to debug problems.  If you watch any short tutorial online (5-10 minutes), it will show you how to use the breakpoint, debugger, and Auto/Local/Watch windows.  Example [quick Youtube search](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sACkw915kmg). Regarding what code to show, I was suggesting that you post the code where you execute `.ShowDialog()`, or even the xaml and code-behind of the `Window` (NameOfBadWindow.xaml and NameOfBadWindow.xaml.cs) that you're trying to show.

Comment: @TamBui I've added the code you wanted, and as I see in the video I even did use the Breakpoint right by myself but I cannot see any values that have assigned "null" to them and as soon as I step into the .ShowDialog() the Error happens.

And I just want to say it again: I already have one button working, with the exact same code. Its just the second button that does not work somehow.

Comment: Try following [these instructions](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_AYGryH9aGbSTSyMQSdxsxv2Tuv9rlLL/view?usp=sharing) that I posted for you. From what I can see, you have a collection in your DataGrid that has some kind of Dictionary<Key,Value>, and the issue is that one of your values is null, which your window doesn't like.

Comment: @TamBui Yes, I have a Datagrid with a Datacontext set to an Observable Collection. There are objects in this collection and all objects have all values they need.
I've tried your instructions and still nothing shows up except this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try and **disable Virtualization** in the DataGrid of the dialog you show:
`VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"`. Also try and disable `EnableRowVirtualization` `EnableColumnVirtualization` in case it's enabled.

Solves this issue at least for some people.
For example here: [Application crashes upon scrolling up/down in Template Column with ComboBoxes and TextBoxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52084402/application-crashes-upon-scrolling-up-down-in-template-column-with-comboboxes-an)

Comment: Okay, bad luck. If you try `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"`?
According to the Stacktrace you are using a VirtualizingStackPanel...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am absolutely dumb and I even want to apologize for this question.

Thank you @TamBui for teaching me new things in Debugging, my inital error is deep in a Factory where I did not add a object to my ObservableCollection.

I even checked if the Collection is empty with
`if(!ObservableCollection.Any)` but it didnt execute. Weird.

Comment: Glad u got it figured out.